# MySQL count not returning 0 for specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, loops, count, zero

I have the following code:

```
SELECT c.c_id, c_name, count(h.h_id) AS count 
FROM c
LEFT JOIN h ON h.h_id = c.c_id
WHERE h.info_id = 25
AND c.c_id = {$sqlrow['c_id']}
GROUP BY c.c_id
```

I am using PHP to select the `c_id` in the WHERE statement, unfortunately if there is a `c_id` with a count of 0 for the `h_id` then no rows are selected. Is there a way to get SQL to represent no rows selected as a count of 0?

Because no rows are selected for a specific `c_id` by `WHERE` loop in PHP appears to skip the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT
  c.c_id,
  c_name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(h.h_id)
    FROM h
    WHERE h.h_id = c.c_id
    AND h.info_id = 25
  ) AS count 
FROM c
WHERE c.c_id = {$sqlrow['c_id']}
```

Comment: Hi @Bart, I tried your example and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With PHP and mySQL when I may run into this type of situation I use a simple IF statement directly under the query like

```
$sql = "SELECT your, stuff, here";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if($mysql_num_rows($qry) == 0) {
    # DO YOUR STUFF HERE FOR NO RESULTS
} else {
    # DO YOUR STUFF HERE FOR RESULTS
}
```

I hope this gets you on the right path, and yeah, I know the SQL is invalid, it's irrelevant as you already have your SQL - it is just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.c_id, c_name, count(h.h_id) AS count 
FROM c
LEFT JOIN h ON h.h_id = c.c_id
and h.info_id = 25
AND c.c_id = {$sqlrow['c_id']}
GROUP BY c.c_id
```

by putting a condition on the h table into the where clause, it converts left join to inner join. Because the where clause condition will never be true if the column value for h.info is null from the left join, so the row is filtered out.